# Escape single quote in Xtend template expression

Tags: syntax, escaping, syntax-error, xtend

I have a very simple question, but could not figure it out by Google search, please help.

I want to produce this string `'\u0000'` (note the simple quote marks surrounding it!) using the following simple Xtend method containing a template expression:

```
def String makeDefaultChar()
{
   ''''\u0000''''
}
```

However, this is not accepted as proper syntax (probably because of the four `''''`. Is there an escape character for this use case or what is the right syntax?

Thank you in advance!

P.S.

Of course I could use plain Java string like this `"'\\u0000'"` to achieve the same, but I want to use an Xtend template expression.

My Xtend version is: `2.9.1.v201512180746`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "escaping" in template expressions, so you have to use the workaround you mentioned:

```
'''«"'\\u0000'"»'''
```

or

```
'''«"'"»\u0000«"'"»'''
```

Related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xtend-lang/bVZ0nKmQGAI

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are allowed within Xtend templates as long as they do not occur at the beginning or the end of the template. So a simple workaround is to add an empty expression before/after the single quote:

```
'''«»'\u0000'«»'''
```